# Jquery cycle rss feeds question

Tags: jquery, rss, cycle

Quick question from a jQuery newbie.

This jQuery cycle code cycles twitter feeds (butler basketball one) - http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/
is there an equivalent that could cycle RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rssreader
and this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed
I think they are both easy to use :)
 ;)

Comment: +1: Apparently there's *already* a server-side solution. Well played :)

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Simplepie does the same thing as googlefeeds doesn't it? I might try that. it was more the cycling I was interested in than getting the feeds in.

Answer (score 0):

Not universally, since unless you're fetching an rss feed from the same domain (which I doubt), you'll run into cross-domain issues. You might consider writing a server-side solution that would parse a remote rss feed and output the fields you care about as JSONP.